# Подскажите, как правильно реализовать мою идею в postgresql? Необходимо добавлять из одной таблицы в другую в соответствии с определенным условием

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

У меня есть две таблицы accounts и technical_base.
В таблице  accounts скрипт заполняется автоматически, но не все столбцы. Мне нужно взять данные из technical_base таблицы для заполнения.

Мои таблицы:

```
                **Technical_base**          
source  model   rated_energy    general_tarif
info_1  s9         1300          5
info_1  a10        1200          5
info_2  s9         1300          3.5
info_2  a10        1200          3.5


                   **accounts**                                     
source  object     redirect   model  number_of_cars rated_energy    general_tariff  personal_tariff personal_energy result_for_the_month    date
info_1  info_object Client_1    s9          info                                           Info       info                info              info
info_2  info_object Client_2    s9          info                                           info      info                 info              info
info_1  info_object Client_3    a10         info                                           info       info                info              info
info_2  info_object Cleint_4    a10         info                                           info       info                info              info
```

Какой результат хочу:

```
                     **accounts**                                       
source  object  redirect    model   number_of_cars  rated_energy    general_tariff  personal_tariff personal_energy result_for_the_month    date
info_1  info_object Client_1 s9           info          1300               5          info               info              info             info
info_2  info_object Client_2 s9           info          1300               3.5        info               info              info             info
info_1  info_object Client_3 a10          info          1200               5          info               info             info              info
info_2  info_object Cleint_4 a10          info          1200               3.5        info               info             info              info
```

в результате мне нужен правильный запрос, чтобы он находил данные из технической таблицы и сравнивал их в таблице accounts и заполнил столбцы rated_energy и    general_tarif так информация есть ток там.

что ун их общего у таблиц это sourcе и model, по ним он должен искать у technical_base и записывать accounts.

Я думал о вариантах с ключами, но я думаю, что это сложно...

Если нужны еще доп. инфа или код для создание таблиц то пишите скину.

Запрос на таблицы
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=92b67e79ece3bd86b5c579bec03639f9

Получаеться на такой запрос но он не правильный...

```
UPDATE accounts SET rated_energy = (SELECT rated_energy FROM technical_base WHERE technical_base.model = accounts.model and  technical_base.source = accounts.source) AND
SET general_tariff = (SELECT general_tariff FROM technical_base WHERE technical_base.model = accounts.model and  technical_base.source = accounts.source) WHERE EXISTS (SELECT rated_energy FROM technical_base WHERE technical_base.model = accounts.model and  technical_base.source = accounts.source) AND SELECT general_tariff FROM technical_base
WHERE technical_base.model = accounts.model and  technical_base.source = accounts.source);
```

Comment: Собственно самый что ни на есть тривиальный UPDATE по условию равенства двух полей. [UPDATE syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html).

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=bfeac848820d9ff921ad549a7e87e126 @akina

Comment: @Akina сделал ссылку с таблицами

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=92b67e79ece3bd86b5c579bec03639f9 @Akina

Comment: Вообще-то данные в тексте и в fiddle должны полностью совпадать. И соответствовать требуемому ответу. Иначе как проверять корректность решения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE accounts a  -- обновляемая таблица
SET rated_energy = t.rated_energy,  -- что и чем обновляем
    general_tariff = t.general_tariff
FROM technical_base t  -- откуда берём данные для обновления
WHERE a.source = t.source AND a.model = t.model  -- устанавливаем соответствие
  AND (a.rated_energy IS NULL OR a.general_tariff IS NULL);  -- проверяем, надо ли обновлять
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=066c158c05ef5c177e14041a62ab2bd3

Т.е. обновляем только записи, где есть хотя бы одно незаполненное поле.

Comment: Спасибо большое, я не знал что можно добавлять значение и нашел у себя ошибку

Comment: @Alexey Я ж дал ссылку на документацию! и там не только подробное описание, но и дофига примеров...